# MVC URL routing is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is my Global.asax , all I want to map another url format to controller and action.

```
        //Matching to auctions-index-Testing
        //Why this one is not matching to auction-index
        routes.MapRoute("TestUrl", "{controller}-{action}-{name}",
            new { name = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


        //Matching to Home/Index/1
        //Matching to Home/Index
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I am wondering why auction-index is giving me "Resource not found error". Name is optional and it is first entry in table. so it should be matched with the URL

any help and suggestion would be grateful

Comment: what url are you getting a 404 for ?

Comment: http://servername/auctions-index is giving me 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead ::

```
routes.MapRoute("TestUrl", "{controller}-{action}-{name}",
    new { controller = "auctions", 
          action = "index", 
          name = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: but why i need to hardcode the controller and action as I am supplying it through URL . it does not make sense.

Comment: @paritosh, the default route defined by MVC is doing the same thing. That's why its overriding your new route. If you want to run all the URL by this manner than change the default route instead of creating new route.

Comment: okay I agreed , But according to format I made name as optional and now controller and action part should be match to first match not to last one. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: The reason behind this is that MVC Routing respect ordering route. Your last route must be generic as possible, and your previous route must be specific as possible.

Comment: I tried your code still not working.I dont what i missed.   routes.MapRoute("TestUrl", "{controller}-{action}-{name}",
                new { controller = "Auction", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

Comment: you missed the s in aution. ;) i wrote "auctions" which is the name of your controller.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31813/discussion-between-paritosh-and-kundan-singh-chouhan)